# Copy paste from excel, difference between line break in cell and row delimiter

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

We need to offer to our customers a way of copy pasting an excel to a table in a web application.
We split rows with line breaks, and columns with tabulation.

The problems is that in a single cell you can have line break so the `split(\n)` will simply understand that there is a new row.

```
    const rows = event.target.value.split('\n');
    for (let row of rows) {
      const values = row.split('\t');
    }
```

With the code above, when there are no line break in cells we can get a nice table of the copy paste, but as soon as there are linebreaks in cells, everything is move to one row and break everything.

How can I differentiate line breaks for delimiting rows and line breaks in cells ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the small example where I've copy-pasted the Excel data into Notepad++ and we can see that `cat\nfish` is quoted:

[image]

So you can treat the content being pasted to the web application as tab separated values (tsv) and parse them as such.

In the snippet below `tsvStringToArray` is adapated from [here](https://gist.github.com/Jezternz/c8e9fafc2c114e079829974e3764db75) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/example-javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data) too). Note that an extra row is being returned because of that final `CR LF` after `dog`. In real life you should probably look for a library to do this for you. You might look at D3 as something that can run in the browser.

For `arrToTable`, I assume you must have a better effort of `arrToTable`. However, you should consider if you need to recreate the newline in the HTML.

```js
const target = document.getElementById("input");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

const tsvStringToArray = (data) => {
  const re = /(\t|\r?\n|\r|^)(?:"([^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*)"|([^\t\r\n]*))/gi
  const result = [[]]
  let matches
  while ((matches = re.exec(data))) {
    if (matches[1].length && matches[1] !== "\t") result.push([])
    result[result.length - 1].push(
      matches[2] !== undefined ? matches[2].replace(/""/g, '"') : matches[3]
    )
  }
  //console.log(result);
  return result
}

const arrToTable = arr => {
  let tbl = document.createElement("table");
  for (row of arr) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (cell of row) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      let test = /\n/.test(cell);
      if (test) {
        let items = cell.split(/\n/);
        for ([idx, item] of items.entries()) {
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
          if (idx < items.length) {
            td.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
          }
        }
      } else {
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cell));    
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
  }
  return tbl;
}

target.addEventListener("paste", e => {
  const text = event.clipboardData.getData("text");
  const arr = tsvStringToArray(text).slice(0, -1);
  const el = arrToTable(arr);
  output.appendChild(el);
});
```

```css
div#input {
  height: 90px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: powderblue;
}

table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Paste in blue box:
<div id="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
<p>
<div id="output"></div>
```